# How to fix Manifest merger failed?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova

Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0] C:....\AndroidManifest.xml Error 1
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 22

Answer (score 0):

Update the Module `build.gradle` minSdk to 22 or more api level.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionName "1.0"
        versionCode 1

    }
```

Any phone actually run the api lvl 1.

See the bellow statistics to know more about the api lvl usage:

[image]